# Python pick last Buy_Signal_Price

Tags: python, python-3.x

I had created a simple buy sell function, when a buy signal had executed, it will append to `data['AC'][i]`. Now how do I pick up the LAST buy price on further loop (Under ##Sell signal criteria) ?

Here is the code:

```
def buy_sell(data):

  sigPriceBuy=[]
  sigPricesell=[]
  flag=-1

#============================================================================

  for i in range(len(data)):

    ##Set buy signal criteria
    if data['LSMA5'][i] < data['SMA50'][i] and \
        data['LClose5'][i] < data['LSMA5'][i] and \
        data['AC'][i] < data['LClose10'][i]: 
            
      if flag!=1: 
        sigPriceBuy.append(data['AC'][i])
        sigPricesell.append(np.nan)
        flag=1
      else:
         sigPriceBuy.append(np.nan)
         sigPricesell.append(np.nan)
    
     ##Sell signal criteria
    elif data['AC'][i] > (Here I want to pick up last buy price):
      if flag !=0:
          sigPriceBuy.append(np.nan)
          sigPricesell.append(data['AC'][i])
          flag=0
      else:
          sigPriceBuy.append(np.nan)
          sigPricesell.append(np.nan)
    else:
          sigPriceBuy.append(np.nan)
          sigPricesell.append(np.nan)


  return (sigPriceBuy,sigPricesell)
```

Thanks with Regards

JC

Comment: Please explain your question in detail. Its not explanatory enough.

Comment: What's the data? What's the input and the expected output?